# use a computed column in another column which is a query itself

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've just got a case where I need to use a computed column in the `WHERE` of another column's query

I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Date, RequestedOn) AS [Date], 
    COUNT(*), 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CalculatorLog WHERE CONVERT(Date, RequestedOn) = [Date] AND <other_static_conditions>) AS [Count]
    FROM CalculatorLog
    Group by CONVERT(Date, RequestedOn) Order by [Date] DESC
```

I am trying to implement this in second column of `SELECT` statement. But its an error saying `Invalid Column name [Date]`.

So what are the possible workaround for this..?
One I can think of is creating a view which I always do if any such use case arrives.

But for this database, I only have read access. So I cannot create View on this database for this purpose. So I just need to get it done by `SELECT` statement anyhow.

Comment: did you tried using temp tables?

Comment: nope. wld that work with read access only..? @AsshO.Le

Comment: im not sure but you can try it, using `Select * into #temptable from Yourtablewithcomputedcolumn` after that `Select Computedcolumn from #temtable` see what happens, you are just using selects in there.

Comment: store the [Date] value in a variable and then use it.

Comment: Didn't work :-( @AsshO.Le

Comment: can you post your current code?

Comment: Thnx @VijayHulmani. But I hv no idea how to do this..? can u give some exmpl or code..?

Comment: Select all details from the table you are using into a #temptable, after that Do the computed column in the #temptable, then select the columns in the temptable with computed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sum 1 for the condition and 0 otherwise:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(Date, RequestedOn) AS [Date], 
  COUNT(*), 
  SUM(CASE WHEN <other_static_conditions> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count]
FROM CalculatorLog
Group by CONVERT(Date, RequestedOn)
Order by [Date] DESC
```

Comment: u just forgot to put main condition in the query.. which is something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CalculatorLog WHERE CONVERT(Date, RequestedOn) = [Date]`. It is a query for the column

Comment: okay.. I got it.. I do not need to put this as another query. Its really a very gud solution.. Thank u very much.

Comment: @shashwat no, I didn't forget. This query is correct. The original query had no where clause so neither should this one. The "where clause" for the subquery is captured in the case condition.

Answer (score 1):

Replace [Date] column with CONVERT(Date, CL.RequestedOn) in subquery like

```
SELECT CONVERT(Date, CL.RequestedOn) AS [Date], 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CalculatorLog WHERE CONVERT(Date, RequestedOn) = CONVERT(Date, CL.RequestedOn) AND <other_static_conditions>) AS [Count]
    FROM CalculatorLog CL
    Group by CONVERT(Date, CL.RequestedOn) Order by [Date] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions from @Bohemian and @upendra answers your question.  My reply is in regard with the usage of views.  As you said that you can no longer use views as you have read access but you can use common table expression.